# How to optimise a bulk insert?

Tags: postgresql, sql-insert

My code looks like this:

```
LOOP
        EXIT WHEN TIMESTAMP_START >= TIMESTAMP_END;
        INSERT INTO datapoint_values (dp_id, ts, int_value)
        VALUES (NODE_ID, TIMESTAMP_START, INIT_D);

        INIT_D := smooth_random_double(INIT_D, STEP_D, MIN_D, MAX_D);
        TIMESTAMP_START := TIMESTAMP_START + STEP;
END LOOP;
```

I am making a lot (at average 300000) of single inserts. Are there ways to optimise the inserts? For example somehow batch them together and perform a bulk insert. Or are there some other "low-hanging-fruits"?

EDIT 1

```
    CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION smooth_random_double(VAL double precision, STEP double precision,
                                                    MIN double precision,
                                                    MAX double precision) RETURNS double precision AS
    $rand_smooth_double$
    BEGIN
        VAL := VAL + random() * STEP * 2 - STEP;
        IF VAL > MAX THEN
            RETURN MAX;
        ELSIF VAL < MIN THEN
            RETURN MIN;
        END IF;
        RETURN VAL;
    END;
    $rand_smooth_double$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: A single insert with `generate_series()` as the source? What exactly does `some_func()` do?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name ’some_func()’ just changes the value of INIT_D. So basically the next INIT_D depends on the previous. Is it then possible to use generate_series()?

Comment: That depends on what exactly `some_func()` is doing.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name it changes the value of INIT_D within some range.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I have added the function to the description